# Can anyone advise of a way to set a universal quit-application shortcut?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys

I'm moving across from Mac OSX and am quite used to using the Cmd-Q shortcut to quit apps. I appreciate that Linux is set up differently and that different apps have different shortcuts for quitting (e.g. some use Ctrl-Q while others might be Alt-Q, etc.). I'm currently using Ubuntu GNOME.

Would it be possible to create a standard keyboard shortcut for quitting all apps easily and safely in Ubuntu? I'm happy to use a third-party tool or do a bit of further digging.

M

Comment: Hmm... I'm using default settings on 14.04, Alt+F4 always worked for me.

Comment: Sorry Jacob! I'm new to these discussion forums. Will do so now!

Comment: @MichaelStevenson no problem :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Gracefully close a window

The simplest would be to add the following command to a shortcut key of your choice:

```
wmctrl -c :ACTIVE:
```

wmctrl is not installed by default:

```
sudo apt-get install wmctrl
```

from `man wmctrl`:

```
-c <WIN>
    Close the window <WIN> gracefully
```

*Gracefully* closing a window means that if you e.g. made changes to the currently opened file, you will be asked if you want to save the changes etc. This is similar to the <kbd>Cmnd</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>you are used to.

#### To add it to a shortcut key

Choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the command:

```
wmctrl -c :ACTIVE:
```

#### Or, if you are comfortable with Alt + F4

Even much simpler, as mentioned by @Takkat (thanks!), you can simply press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

using **CTRL Q** works to quit an application in Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Thanks so much, Jacob and Kalamalka. These are great suggestions!

Comment: feel free to accept ONE of the answers if you feel they answered your question

Answer (score 1):

Under gnome 40, if you go to settings, keyboard, keyboard shortcuts, windows there is the shortcut `Close window` that is by default `Alt F4` but you can customize.

Answer (score 0):

Many tabs etc in applications can be closed with `ctrl + w`, I set "close applciation" shortcut to `ctrl + shift + W` (which is same as for example chrome to close all, same with vscode) to quit any application. Extremely convenient (Ubuntu Budgie 20.04). I think default otherwise is `alt + f4`. Not so convenient

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd> and I changed it to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd> :D

I am on Debian Bullseye.

Cheers!

Comment: Your answer could be improved by explaining how someone can find the shortcut for their system and then reconfigure it.  As such, this answer doesn't provide any information other than you changed the shortcut on your system.